# Array same element in C

Tags: c, arrays

c finding the array of the same element
A function called rLookupAr() takes in three parameters, array, size and target, and returns the subscript of the last appearance of a number in the array. The parameter size indicates the size of the array. For example, if array is {2,1,3,2,4} and target is 3, it will return 2. With the same array, **if target is 2, it will return 3**. If the required number is not in the array, the function will return –1. The function prototype is given below.

```
int rLookupAr(int array[], int size, int target);
```

Write a C program to test the function.

A sample input and output session is given below:

**Enter array size: 5 Enter 5 numbers: 2 1 3 2 4 Enter the target number: 2 rLookupAr() = 3**

Enter array size: 5 Enter 5 numbers: 2 1 3 2 4 Enter the target number: 5 rLookupAr() = -1

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int rLookupAr(int array[], int size, int target);

int main() {
    int numArray[80];
    int target, i, size;

    printf("Enter array size: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    printf("Enter %d numbers: ", size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        scanf("%d", &numArray[i]);

    printf("Enter the target number: ");
    scanf("%d", &target);

    printf("rLoopupAr(): %d", rLookupAr(numArray, size, target));

    return 0;
} 

int rLookupAr(int array[], int size, int target) {
    int j,i;

    for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
    if(array[i] == target)
       return j;

    return -1;
}
```

I do not know how to implement when same array elements numbers are the same as bolded

Comment: Honestly, your code is atrociously formatted. Please use indentation and a couple of more newlines.

Comment: Also, there is no C++ code shown at all. It's all plain C. Please use correct language tags.

Comment: Please take a look at some C code written by a programmer, so you get an idea of what proper formatting might look like. I'm not going to read this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can code it looping through the array in reverse way like

```
int rLookupAr(int array[], int size, int target) {
    int j;

    for (j = size-1; j >= 0; j--)
        if (array[j] == target)
            return j;

    return -1;
}
```

Or looping through the whole and store the value in a lookup variable

```
int rLookupAr(int array[], int size, int target) {
    int j;
    char found = -1;

    for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
        if (array[j] == target)
            found = j;

    return found;
}
```

Comment: oh i get it now u check the array from the opposite way for the same array element thank you sry for my english